# How to design wireless charging coils so they are resonant?

Tags: coil, wireless-charging, mutual-inductance

I am continuing from this question: [What can I use to increase efficiency of inductive wireless energy transfer instead of factory manufactured ferrite plates?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476392/what-can-i-use-to-increase-efficiency-of-inductive-wireless-energy-transfer-inst/476395?noredirect=1#comment1208668_476395)

I am trying to make somewhat efficient wireless energy transfer for charging a 190mAh 3.7V battery. The plan is to use a rectifier, a voltage regulator and a charging IC MCP738312([datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/6/9/5/MCP738312.pdf)) in the device and generate AC at a few hundreds of kHz from a 12V coming from a 1A regulated wall power adaptor in the charger device.

I am making my own coils because of the size I want them to be by etching multiple layers of copper foil:

[image]

**A new question arose: how do I design the coils so that they are resonant?** It would be great to get an answer that would be easy to understand for someone without education in electrical engineering, if that's possible, as much as it is possible.

Comment: The coils themselves (should) only have a parasitic resonance but that will be at such a high frequency that it's not so suitable for wireless charging. What is done in wireless charging systems is that the **coil** is in parallel with one or more **capacitors**. That forms an LC tank which can resonate. I suggest that you **study** existing wireless charging designs to see what makes them work.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks. So I would have to choose the capacitors depending on what frequency I end up using, right? How would I calculate that?

Comment: *How would I calculate that?* Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit  that's basic EE, I suggest that you do spend some time studying EE basics.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, I am sorry, I know how it's annoying to see really basic questions, I answer a lot of them on Blender Stack Exchange myself, but this is extremely valuable way for me to learn those things and it saves so much time trying to find just the right information to learn plus it remains on the web for others to find. This points me in the right direction to study in more depth. I got to start somewhere. The answer Andy aka gave is really a huge help for me even though I am sure this is basic for most. I do appreciate the patience a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I design the coils so that they are resonant? It would be great
>   to get an answer that would be easy to understand for someone without
>   education in electrical engineering, if that's possible, as much as it
>   is possible.

What you have without resonance is something like this: -

[image]

[Image source](http://techielabs.in/?p=512)

With a capacitor that resonates the receive coil you get a circuit like this: -

[image]

And this magnifies the induced voltage in the receive coil (\$V_{IN}\$ below) because it acts as a very resonant low pass filter like this: -

[image]

<sub>\$R\$ represents the coil and transmit driver losses.</sub>

---

\$V_{OUT}\$ can be made to peak at magnitudes like this: -

[image]

[Interactive filter tool](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html)

With the values chosen, the circuit resonates at about 411 kHz with an amplitude gain (\$G_P\$) of 77.5 or nearly 38 dB. But, bear in mind, that when loading the circuit and taking real power from it, the peaking may drop to a few dB. However, even 6 dB (a doubling of voltage) is a great benefit for the selection of one or two parallel capacitors to hit the sweet-spot.

Also remember to use high-speed diodes in the receiver power rectifier. Something like the ubiquitous 1N400x type diode is wholly unsuitable because of its [reverse recovery time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Reverse-recovery_effect).

You can also do a similar trick for the transmit coil but now, what happens is that you "tickle" a parallel coil and capacitor with a low current and get a much higher current. Sure, it can take several milliseconds to build up but who cares about that?

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely useful.

Comment: Note that the voltage the capacitor "sees" will be much higher than expected while resonating. Usually ceramic, foil, and/or poly capacitors are used with up to 1kV rating (never electrolytic or tantalum.)

Comment: @dtsc thanks a lot for pointing this out

Answer (score 2):

Another answer explains well how a resonating capacitor improves transfer to the receiving coil. In that answer, it is assumed that nearly all the flux from the transmitting coil is efficiently linked to the receiving coil.

> 100% flux linkage of every coil turn to every other turn is a design goal of efficient power transfer, never achieved.

**The form-factor of coils matters.**
 3-D coils with no magnetic amplification having a fixed diameter, multiple turns, plus length) are problematic when flattened to 2-D...length is reduced to zero for a single-layer printed-circuit coil. So multiple turns must be designed into a spiral. These flat 2-D coils have flux-linkage problems that a 3-D coil can reduce.

Flat coil design has conflicting requirements. Many turns require a large-diameter spiral, where inner turns cover a smaller area than outer turns. You'd like all the flux from *every turn* of one coil to link to *every turn* of the other coil. This is not possible with spiral turns. The best you can do is attempt to maximize area of every turn as much as possible. Coil (b) is a better coil than (a), linking more flux to itself and to a coaxial mate:
[image: worse(a) vs. better (b) coil design]

 Coil (b) could benefit from skinny traces; allowing either more turns, or all turns covering a larger area. But skinny traces have more resistance, which dissipates power that could otherwise be transferred to a load.

Comment: I haven’t assumed, in my answer that nearly all the flux links both coils by the way.

Comment: @Andyaka Quite so in your explanation, but those excellent flux-linkage diagrams pretty much show *all of B* linking every turn of both coils.

Comment: Hehe no, they just show the flux lines that DO link both coils. There will be flux that doesn't link both coils and just remains "looping" around the transmit coil.

Comment: @Andyaka Agreed. And for OP's benefit, core-less air-coupled-coils suffer from the *not-shown* lost flux more than ferrite or heavy-iron transformers. Designing efficient power transfer isn't easy when you're unable to direct B loops along a desired path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this confirms my thoughts as far and that is great. Keeping in mind my knowledge level I don't think I am able to aim for an efficient design. My goal is to make a device that functions. If I waste some electricity while charging the 190 mAh battery so be it. For now at least.  I have 11 turns per layer(0.7mm width, 0.055mm thickness, 0.3mm gaps, 7378mm lenght) and plan to have 4 layers in the receiver coil and 6 in the charger. I hope that will be enough for charging 3.7V 190mAh battery with less than 500mA in a couple of hours. I will test and adjust if needed.

Comment: And I realize my mistake with the wording of the question now. I did say 'efficient'. I should have thought it through a bit more carefully...